# Ubuntu 17.04 and wine

Tags: wine

So I upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04 from 16.10 with excitement.

Before when I upgraded to 16.10 , any program (like wine) or any file was deleted and wine was working pretty fine.

But when I upgraded to 17.04, all files and programs were deleted. So I said "Ok,no problem." and tried to install wine.

But there was no wine in Software Center. So I installed wine from terminal but there's no "c disk" when I write c to "search"(I can only access it via .wine).

So who has the problem? Me or Ubuntu?

Comment: linux does not refer to drives by letter. wine has a c drive under dosdevives. what are you trying to do?